# Conferir e exibir mensagem caso a data seja menor que a Data atual

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tenho um campo no meu sistema, onde gostaria de exibir uma mensagem em tempo real caso a data digitada seja anterior a data de hoje. Não seria uma validação, apenas mostrar o alerta. Estou com dificulades com a condição e a sintaxe por não ter o DateTime.Now. Segue o código:

```html
<p>
<label>Último Dia:</label>
<input type="text" class="Data" name="DefinirUltimoDia" id='UltimoDiaDemissao' value=""  />
</p>
```

JS

```js
var formulario = document.getElementById(fAgentes),
     UltimoDiaDemissao = document.getElementById(UltimoDiaDemissao);

        form.onsubmit = function () {
            if (UltimoDiaDemissao.value < DateTime.Now) {
                alert("Atenção: Data do último dia anterior a data atual");
                return false;
            }
```

Comment: Como vem a data no input? DD/MM/YYYY?

Comment: Sim, DD/MM/YYYY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom, incialmente, reparei que você fez referencia ao formulário com a variável `formulario`, mas usou o `onsubmit` numa variável `form`. Não sei se foi erro ou proposital, mas enfim.

Para conseguir a data atual, apenas crie um objeto de data sem parametros. Já a data digitada pelo usuário virá como uma string, não uma data, por isso precisa ser parseada.

Pelo que entendi, quer ver em tempo real, antes da pessoa enviar o formulário, então no caso deve usar o evento `onfocusout`, o evento `onsubmit` só vai dar trigger quando o formulário for enviado.

Veja:

```
var input = document.getElementById('UltimoDiaDemissao'),
    hoje = new Date().setHours(-1),
    ultimoDiaDemissao;

    input.onblur = function () {
       ultimoDiaDemissao = new Date(input.value.split('/').reverse().join('-')).setHours(24);
       if (ultimoDiaDemissao < hoje) {
           alert("Atenção: Data do último dia anterior a data atual");
       } 
}
```

Ok, agora vamos a explicação. `new Date()` retorna a data atual, num objeto de data. Já todo aquele código para o `UltimoDiaDemissao` funciona assim:

Para passar a data para o objeto `Date`, precisa enviar uma string no formato `yyyy-mm-dd`, e a sua string vem no formato brasileiro. Então o `.split('/')` vai dividir o dia, mês e ano em 3 partes numa array, o `reverse()` vai inverter a ordem do array, colocando o ano na frente e o dia no final, e então juntar tudo numa string com o `join('-')` separados com traço ao invés de barra. Só então no final o `setHours(24)` para arrumar um problema com fuso horário UTC, se precisar de detalhamento sobre isso dê uma olhada no objeto `Date` do javascript [e como ele funciona](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Feito isso temos dois objetos de data para serem comparados corretamente, e o resto é só ativar sempre que a pessoa tirar o foco do input de data.

[JsFiddle funcional](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/829337/)

Comment: obrigado cara mas não funcionou. Somente este código deveria solucionar?

Comment: Não tenho como saber sem ver o código todo, incluindo o html.

Comment: Fiz um jsfiddle funcional, também modifiquei um pouco do código na minha resposta pois tinha um erro, dê uma olhada.

Comment: agora sim funciou perfeitamente!!

Comment: Marque a resposta então, por favor, para as pessoas que possam vir a checar essa pergunta futuramente